# Фильтр на столбец DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Не могу понять как реализовать фильтр на столбце datagrid например как на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Кто делал, подскажите как?

Comment: Ну а вы хоть как-то пробовали?

Comment: @Андрей даже не могу представить как это сделать. В WinForms я использовал вот это https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480727.aspx#datagridviewautofiltercolumnheadercell_topic4

Comment: Берите какой-нибудь Popup и размечайте его как нужно, потом по клику по кнопке показывайте его... Вопрос слишком обширный чтобы дать на него ответ в рамках StackOverflow. Пробуйте, разбивайте задачу на более мелкие. Что не получается - спрашивайте

Comment: @Андрей а как кнопку на столбец датагрида навесить что бы вызывать popup? Нужно редактировать сам датагрид? Я еще ни разу ничего подобного не делал, может сможете дать направление куда мне двигаться?

Comment: Пример: https://pastebin.com/fsSXYX7g